# Rust Tokio "future cannot be sent between threads safely ", How to use watch::channel to share Vec<u8> data?

Tags: multithreading, rust, producer-consumer, rust-tokio

The project is implementing a TcpListener service. It monitors the pc events and broadcasts to the TCP clients. As the demands(one producer and many consumers). But the code raises "future cannot be sent between threads safely" error:

```rust
use tokio;
use tokio::{io::AsyncWriteExt, net::TcpStream, sync::watch};
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    
    let (tx, mut rx) = watch::channel::<Vec<u8>>(vec![]);

    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080").await?;

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        while rx.changed().await.is_ok() {
            stream.write(&*rx.borrow()).await;
        }
    });

    tx.send(vec![1u8, 2u8])?;

    Ok(())
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=use%20tokio%3B%0D%0Ause%20tokio%3A%3A%7Bio%3A%3AAsyncWriteExt%2C%20net%3A%3ATcpStream%2C%20sync%3A%3Awatch%7D%3B%0D%0A%23%5Btokio%3A%3Amain%5D%0D%0Aasync%20fn%20main()%20-%3E%20anyhow%3A%3AResult%3C()%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20(tx%2C%20mut%20rx)%20%3D%20watch%3A%3Achannel%3A%3A%3CVec%3Cu8%3E%3E(vec!%5B%5D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20stream%20%3D%20TcpStream%3A%3Aconnect(%22127.0.0.1%3A8080%22).await%3F%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tokio%3A%3Aspawn(async%20move%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20while%20rx.changed().await.is_ok()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20stream.write(%26*rx.borrow()).await%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tx.send(vec!%5B1u8%2C%202u8%5D)%3F%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Ok(())%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

gives:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:9:18
    |
9   |       tokio::spawn(async move {
    |  __________________^
10  | |         while rx.changed().await.is_ok() {
11  | |             stream.write(&*rx.borrow()).await;
12  | |         }
13  | |     });
    | |_____^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = help: within `impl Future<Output = ()>`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `std::sync::RwLockReadGuard<'_, Vec<u8>>`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src/main.rs:11:40
    |
11  |             stream.write(&*rx.borrow()).await;
    |                            ----------- ^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `rx.borrow()` maybe used later
    |                            |
    |                            has type `tokio::sync::watch::Ref<'_, Vec<u8>>` which is not `Send`
note: `rx.borrow()` is later dropped here
   --> src/main.rs:11:46
    |
11  |             stream.write(&*rx.borrow()).await;
    |                                              ^
help: consider moving this into a `let` binding to create a shorter lived borrow
   --> src/main.rs:11:27
    |
11  |             stream.write(&*rx.borrow()).await;
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn`
   --> /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.22.0/src/task/spawn.rs:163:21
    |
163 |         T: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ^^^^ required by this bound in `tokio::spawn`
```

When I change the `Vec<u8>` to `u8` `&str`, it works. Vec, String, and other complex types will raise exceptions.

I searched on google, but still confused. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think because `Ref<_,T>` itself isn't implementing `Send` and you need to turn this type into something that's `Send`. I think the only sensible way is to just clone it first before writing it. Seems to work.

Also, you need to use `borrow_and_update` to mark the value as "seen". This is to make sure that you're not writing the same value to `stream` repeatedly.

```rust
use tokio;
use tokio::{io::AsyncWriteExt, net::TcpStream, sync::watch};
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let (tx, mut rx) = watch::channel::<Vec<u8>>(vec![]);

    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080").await?;

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        while rx.changed().await.is_ok() {
            let coba = rx.borrow_and_update().clone();
            stream.write(&coba).await;
        }
    });

    tx.send(vec![1u8, 2u8])?;

    Ok(())
}
```